# Android service and AlarmManager not stopping

Tags: android

Hello everyone i am creating a service in my Activity name sliding where map with GPS pointing is also runing. my service is periodically checking(Using AlarmManager) response from server using JSON, if response is true new activity starts. My new activity is only for 30 sec and when my new Activity starts service should stop and again starts. My requirement is service should be running while my app is not on foreground( mean if I am busy with other apps the service should be running).
My Problem is that when response comes true new activity starts but service is not stopping(Basically AlarmManager is continuously calling service) and new Activity is starting again and again.
On my sliding activity on the Pause() method i stop AlarmManager it works me only if app is on foreground but if i click on Home button or open any thing from task bar service my service stopped.
Is there any way to stop AlarmManager in new Activity?? so that when my new Activity open service should stop.(my basic task is to stop service when new activity opens)
or any other solution??

here is my java code onStartCommand() method where service is communicating with server

### service.java

```
           public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, final int flags, int startId) {
     try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 

                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){

                Intent call = new Intent(CallService.this, CallScreen.class);


                    call.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(call);


                }}}
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
         return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
```

### Main Activity

```
               @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.sliding);
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 40);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, service.class);


        // Add extras to the bundle
        intent.putExtra("foo", "bar");



        pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

         alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int i;
        i=15;
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                i* 1000, pintent);


        startService(intent);

             }
```

and here is my activity starting in service

### call Activity

```
          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.call);

     }
```

Now when service start call activity service should stop and AlarmManager also stop to calling the service

Comment: Why dont you send a broadcast when your application comes to foreground and in receiver just stop the service... ?

Comment: how i send broadcast in foreground and how i will recieve??

Comment: In your service class register a receiver. now you can send a broadcast from your activity that has come to foreground (Make a BaseActivity get rid of rewriting the code). In onReceive of ur register just call stopservice() method or stopself().

Answer (score 0):

When you want to stop and cancel your Alarm Manager , you need to cancel the Alarm

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,id, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

`id` -> passHereThe same ID which you have already used to start the Alarm in your application

Comment: Basically I am starting my new activity in service as it is checking background response and when it came true new activity

Comment: how can i stop AlarmManager in second activity while AlarmManger is starting in first Activity

Comment: I have dine as given but my new activity starts and hanged

Comment: no error in the logcat basically server is giving me response for 30 second and i have to stop service for 30 sec so that it will not get the response for 30 from server. in these 30 sec i have to run a activity, but when server response is true or 1 activity starts but alarm manager again calls service and activity again starts and so on by implementing above code my activity which have counter hangs counter hangs not working

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a service with receiver:**

```
public class ApplicationMine extends Service{
    public static final String ACTION_STOP_SERVICE = "com.package.name.ACTION_STOP_SERVICE";
    public  void log(String whatever){
        Log.e(" Service state : ", whatever);
    } 


    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        log("onCreate");

            registerReceiver(stopBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_STOP_SERVICE));
            //register your receiver here. This will keep looking for the ACTION_STOP_SERVICE action.

    }



    protected BroadcastReceiver stopBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            log("onReceive");


            stopSelf(); // or   stopService(name);

        }

    };
    public void onDestroy()
    { 
        log("onDestroy");
            unregisterReceiver(stopBroadcastReceiver);

        super.onDestroy();

    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

---

**Now you can have a BaseActivity like below:**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    public void log(String whatever){
        Log.e(" CCCCCCC state: ", whatever);
    }



    public void stopUpdates( String action) 
    {
        Log.d("", "A.R. stopLocationUpdate()");
        // let's broadcast location data to any activity waiting for updates
        Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

---

Now here goes your other activities

```
 public class B extends BaseActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            stopUpdates(ApplicationMine.ACTION_STOP_SERVICE);
        }
}
```

---

Excuse me if any optimal approach misses here. Still I hope you are good to go. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: let me tell in which activity i have to call my service with AlarmManager??

Comment: i already mention my service is stopped but my AlarmManger calls it again. i want to stop alarmmanger when my new activity starts my code is given above